# How to change array form to [0] => ... [1] =>

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm struggling to change structure of array. from As is to To be. Any idea will helps!

From interactive shell As is:

```
php > $a = array('id1' => '5 alarms',
php (     'id2' => '4 alarms',
php (     'id3' => '2 alarms',
php (     'id4' => '1 alarms');
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [id1] => 5 alarms
    [id2] => 4 alarms
    [id3] => 2 alarms
    [id4] => 1 alarms
)
php > $b[] = $a;
php > print_r($b);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 5 alarms
            [id2] => 4 alarms
            [id3] => 2 alarms
            [id4] => 1 alarms
        )
```

But I want to put it each of the element
To be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 5 alarms
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id2] => 4 alarms
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id3] => 2 alarms
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id4] => 1 alarms
        )

)
```

How do I do this?!

Comment: I don't get it ;( any examples?

Comment: Are you explicitly asking how to do this on the shell, or are you just asking for the general syntax to define such an array? Are you asking about creating the array in this format to begin with, or are you asking how to transform given input from the first into the second format?

Comment: @04FS yeah how to do this on shell or vscode whatever : )

Comment: Guess you are simply looking for something as trivial as https://3v4l.org/l4PJ9

Answer (score 1):

You would like to define another array and iterate for each original array key ('id1',..'id4') with the value to another array:

```
$b= array();              
foreach( $a as $key => $value ){
    array_push($b, [$key => $value]);
}
```

**<kbd>[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5fe0401fb42d2921d91530951e45b08b93647974)</kbd>**

Alternatively:

```
$b= array();              
foreach( $a as $key => $value ){
    $b[] = [$key => $value];
}
```

**<kbd>[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3a30dff851b4712ba10770d711a0a10a2da0fed)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$b = array_map(function($k) use ($a) {
  return [$k => $a[$k] ];
}, array_keys($a));
```

or

```
$b = array_map(function($k, $v) {
  return [$k => $v ];
}, array_keys($a), array_values($a));
```